# Apache & HTTPS : Htaccess 301 Redirection on multi domain website

Tags: apache, .htaccess, redirect, mod-rewrite

I use, on my website two domains, files are on a same folder

```
root/index1.php
```

is main page of http://domain1.xyz

And

```
root/index2.php
```

is main page of http://domain2.xyz

I need to force Apache to redirect all http:// on https:// on both domain

I know I can use on .htaccess :

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{SERVER_PORT} 80
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ https://domain1.xyz/$1 [R=301,L]
```

For a unique domain but I can't find a solution for two

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Replace your domainname with `% {HTTP_HOST }` .

```
 RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{SERVER_PORT} 80
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ https://%{HTTP_HOST}/$1 [R=301,L]
```